# Where do I find the environment entry mapping screen in JBoss

Tags: web-applications, jboss, web, jboss7.x

I am trying to migrate an application from OC4J to JBoss, but I can not find the environment entry mapping screen in JBoss 7.

Is there one? If so, where is it? If not, how do I do it?

Our app has the following values in the web.xml:

```
<env-entry>
  <env-entry-name>SERVLET_PATH</env-entry-name>
  <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
</env-entry>
```

In OC4J these can been seen in the Environment Entry Mappings screen (also I can see them in Websphere under the Environment entries for Web modules screen).

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: I haven't used JBoss extensively, but to my knowledge, there is no such tooling. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162908/interactive-application-deployment-on-jboss for my related, more generic question regarding the lack of deployment tooling in JBoss.